# Как уйти от рекурсии?

Tags: python, рекурсия

Доброго дня!

Есть программка:

```
def X(m): return m and (2*m-1)*X(m-1) or 1
def Y(m): return m and (4*m*m-8*m+3)*Y(m-2)+7*X(m-2) or 1
b=10**12
print (Y(b*4)*b)/X(b*4)
```

Естественно, компьютер не справляется, каким образом можно уйти от рекурсии, чтобы не было переполнения стека или, может, упростить логику, чтобы было реально дождаться результата. Пробовал проходить по шагам, чтобы вывести формулу приращения при каждом шаге, изучал логику, расписывал на бумажке, но тонкое место ускользает от моего взгляда.

```
1: 3
2: 7
3: 11
4: 14
5: 18
...
10: 37
...
100: 374
...
200: 749
```

Т.е., грубо говоря, ответ около b*3,745, что вполне реально вывести, вопрос только, каким образом этот алго оптимизировать, чтобы он мог отработать за приемлемое время.

Comment: если не рекурсия, то итерация. делайте бесконечный цикл, обновляйте переменную, пока она не станет выполнять необходимые условия.

Comment: У вас нет условия конца рекурсии, нужно ограничение на m ввести.

Comment: задача полная, имеет решение, ограничение не нужно, щапистите для маленьких чисел и убедитесь

Comment: вот только при 249 уже не хочет работать. И я понимаю питон, потому что X(248) имеет длину 562 цифры. Что будет при 10**12 я даже не берусь оценивать. Тут нужно похоже вначале напрячь математику хорошо.

Comment: @KoVadim, именно её, родимую)

Comment: Чтобы уйти от рекурсии, надо уйти от рекурсии. Простите, не сдержался.

@KoVadim: Не надо ничего напрягать, просто используйте float.

Comment: @VadimTukaev и сколько, по-Вашему, размерность обычного float? Она обычно редко превышает [10^308](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.python/7txrnregzn8/K9bOERR2evoJ). А там при 248 уже порядка 10^562.

Comment: @KoVadim: Да, Вы правы. Завтра с утра попробую "напрячь математику".

Comment: Кстати, функция Y уходит в бесконечный цикл при нечетных m, а функция X - при отрицательных. Нужно делать так:

    def X(m): return m>0 and (2*m-1)*X(m-1) or 1
    def Y(m): return m>0 and (4*m*m-8*m+3)*Y(m-2)+7*X(m-2) or 1

Comment: не нужно, т.к. при вызове b умножается на 4, потому m заведомо чётная, и m-2 заведомо положительная

Comment: @Isaev, а не могли вы бы озвучить изначальную задачу, из которой получается данная вычислительная схема? Мало приятного разбираться в записях вида expr1 and expr2 or expr3 без скобок.

Comment: @dzhioev, мне тоже кажется, что вот так сформулировать было бы лучше:

    def X(m): return 1 if m == 0 else (2 * m - 1) * X(m - 1)
    def Y(m): return 1 if m == 0 else (4 * m * m - 8 * m + 3) * Y(m - 2) + 7 * X(m - 2)

Comment: @dzhioev, это изначальная задача. Получить результат работы программы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так-с, давайте по порядку:

```
def X(m): return m and (2*m-1)*X(m-1) or 1
def Y(m): return m and (4*m*m-8*m+3)*Y(m-2)+7*X(m-2) or 1
b=10**12
print (Y(b*4)*b)/X(b*4)
```

Даже если забыть про лимит рекурсии в python`е, то про скорость выполнения забыть не получится: она будет явно больше нескольких сотен (если не тысяч) лет.

**Немного оптимизируем наши вычисления.**

Для начала заметим, что для вычисления, например, `X(m)` требуется знание `X(m-1)`, поэтому можно будет ускорить вычисления убрав рекурсию (пример тов. [@insolor](/users/1365/insolor)):

```
def X1(m):
    p = 1
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        p *= 2*i-1
    return p
```

Далее, поскольку `Y(m)` выражается через `Y(m - 2)`, то выразив аналогичным образом и `X(m)` (т.е. через `X(m - 2)`) мы сможем проводить вычисления в одном цикле:

```
X(m) = (2 * m - 1) * X(m - 1)
X(m - 1) = (2 * (m - 1) - 1) * X(m - 2) = (2 * m - 3) * X(m - 2) =>
=> X(m) = (2 * m - 3) * (2 * m - 1) * X(m - 2)
```

Перед слиянием функций немного изменим нашу функцию `Y(m)`:

```
Y(m) = (4 * m * m - 8 * m + 3) * Y(m - 2) + 7 * X(m - 2) для m > 0, иначе 1
=> Y(m) = (4 * m * m - 8 * m + 4 - 1)...
=> Y(m) = (4 * (m * m - 2 * m + 1) - 1)...
=> Y(m) = (4 * (m - 1)**2 - 1)...
=> Y(m) = ((2 * (m - 1) - 1) * (2 * (m - 1) + 1))...
=> Y(m) = (2 * m - 3) * (2 * m - 1)...
```

Таким образом получим нашу ускоренную функцию `Y(m)`:

```
def Y(m):
    p = 1
    o = 1
    for i in range(2, m + 1, 2):
        current_mul = (2 * i - 3) * (2 * i - 1)
        p *= current_mul
        p += 7 * o;

        #X(i)
        o *= current_mul

    return p
```

Вот только для `m = 4 * 10**12` результат будет получен через пару десятков лет, если не позже...

Поэтому надо "хорошо напрячь математику" и оптимизировать не только вычисления, но и формулы.

**"Напрягаем математику"**

Мы получили следующие выражения:

```
X(m) = (2 * m - 3) * (2 * m - 1) * X(m - 2)
Y(m) = (2 * m - 3) * (2 * m - 1) * Y(m - 2) + 7 * X(m - 2)
```

Нам необходимо найти `Y(m) / X(m)`, т.е.:

```
(2*m - 3) * (2*m - 1) * Y(m - 2) + 7 * X(m - 2)       Y(m - 2)             7
--------------------------------------------------- = -------- + --------------------
(2*m - 3) * (2*m - 1) * X(m - 2)                      X(m - 2)   (2*m - 3) * (2*m - 1)
```

Продолжая таким образом вычисления получим, что необходимо найти частичную сумму ряда, n-ый член которого определяется формулой:

```
an = 7 / ((2*n - 3) * (2*n - 1))
```

Надо только не забыть, что `Y(0)` и `X(0)` у нас выбиваются из этого ряда. Таким образом нам надо найти сумму:

```
Y(m) / X(m) = 1 + (a2 + a4 + a6 + ... + am)
```

Честно, как работать с рядами уже забыл (давно это было), поэтому воспользовался гуглом и нашел эту [статью](http://www.mathprofi.ru/kak_naiti_summu_ryada.html). Там есть подобный пример (Пример 5).

Сделав аналогичные вычисления для нашего ряда получим, что n-ый член ряда равен `7/2 / (2*n - 3) - 7/2 / (2 * n - 1)`. Поскольку 7/2 общий множитель каждого члена, то его можно вынести за скобку:

```
Y(m) / X(m) = 1 + 3.5 * (a2 + a4 + a6 + ...)
an = 1 / (2*n - 3) - 1 / (2*n - 1)
```

таким образом исходная сумма ряда (не всего выражения, а ряда!!!) равна:

```
1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ... + 1/(2*n - 3) - 1/(2 * n - 1)
```

Этот ряд показался знакомым, но поскольку ничего уже не помню, то решил опять воспользоваться поиском и нашел, что он равен `pi / 4` ([доказательство](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.ru/2007/11/leibniz-1-13-15-17.html))

Таким образом получаем, что

```
Y(m) / X(m) = 1 + 3.5 * PI / 4 = 3.748893571891069
```

**Вернемся к задаче**

Нам надо найти `m * Y(4*m) / X(4*m)` для `m = 10**12`.

Т.к. мы нашли точное решение (конечно, без части `m * ...`), а в задаче приведено примерное (т.е. решение с определенной точностью), то наше решение может немного не совпадать с ожидаемым. Например, найдите ответ для `m = 10` в исходном решении и сравните его с нашим - ответы будут разными.

Поскольку мы знаем как найти n-ый член (`an = 7 / ((2*n - 3) * (2*n - 1))`), то мы можем оценить его влияние на конечный результат:

```
an = 7. / (2 * n - 3) / (2 * n - 1) = 1.093750000000547e-25 для n = 4 * 10**12
```

Если нам необходимо вывести только целую часть исходного выражения, то наш ответ должен будет подойти. Если же надо будет вывести еще и дробную часть, то у меня пока мыслей нет что и как надо делать, т.к. an гораздо меньше найденной нами точности `10**-15`

Comment: И я писал выше про 20 лет - это были примерные результаты тестов на другом компе. Здесь смотрю - время показывает уже больше 100 лет, так что реально время могло быть и больше 200-300 лет )) А значит исходный код работал бы не одну тысячу лет - быстрее было бы подождать появление кубитов и выполнить код там )

Ну либо провести мозговой штурм и получить результат за пару часов ))

Comment: @Isaev, в той ветке у меня комментарии уже закончились. В ответ я и сам мог преобразовать, но там было кусками, поэтому создал полноценный ответ.

Ряд получил когда искал "как найти сумму ряда": нашел статью из ответа, привел к виду `an = 1 / (2*n - 3) - 1 / (2*n - 1)`, а там уже просто подставлял значения `n = 2, 4, 6...`, в результате и получил этот ряд.

Вы мой ответ видно не до конца прочитали, там приведены шаги получения конечного результата ))

Comment: @BOPOH, огромное спасибо, красивое решение! Я бы никогда не догадался наверное, что всё сводится к ряду из формулы Лейбница)

Comment: "Если нам необходимо вывести только целую часть исходного выражения, то наш ответ должен будет подойти."

Да, судя по начальному коду ответ - целое число
python почему-то посчитал выражение ´10**12*(1+7/8*math.pi)´ с огромной погрешностью, но калькулятор windows вполне справился, ответ совпал

Answer (score 3):

Первая функция разворачивается так:

```
def X1(m):
    p = 1
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        p *= 2*i-1
    return p
```

Вторая функция разворачивается похожим образом.

**UPD.** Со второй функцией все оказалось не так уж просто.

Неоптимизированный вариант:

```
def Y1(m):
    p = 1

    if m>0 and m%2==0:
        k=2
    else:
        k=1

    for i in range(k, m+1, 2):
        p = (4*i*i-8*i+3)*p+7*X1(i-2)

    return p
```

Оптимизированный вариант:

```
def Y2(m):
    p = 1

    if m>0 and m%2==0:
        k=2
    else:
        k=1

    x = 1
    for i in range(k, m+1, 2):
        p = (4*i*i-8*i+3)*p+7*x

        if i-1>0:
            x *= 2*(i-1)-1

        x *= 2*i-1
    return p
```

Замеры производительности:

```
In [8]:

%timeit Y(800)

1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop

In [9]:

%timeit Y1(800)

10 loops, best of 3: 141 ms per loop

In [10]:

%timeit Y2(800)

100 loops, best of 3: 3.28 ms per loop
```

**UPD2.** Если считать, что m всегда четное, то можно избавиться от лишних условий:

```
def Y3(m):
    assert(m%2==0)
    p = 1
    x = 1
    for i in range(2, m+1, 2):
        p = (4*i*i-8*i+3)*p+7*x
        x *= (2*(i-1)-1)*(2*i-1)
    return p
```

Производительность выросла незначительно:

```
In [31]:

%timeit Y2(10000)

1 loops, best of 3: 517 ms per loop

In [30]:

%timeit Y3(10000)

1 loops, best of 3: 486 ms per loop
```

Теперь вернемся к выражению `(Y(b*4)*b)/X(b*4)` и предположим, что при больших b выражение приближается к `K*b`. Это действительно похоже на правду:

```
for b in range(100, 5000, 100):
    print(b, (Y3(b*4)*b)/X1(b*4) / b)

100 3.746706075309011
200 3.747799822318314
300 3.7481644053509937
400 3.7483466969444748
500 3.748456071918413
600 3.7485289885735598
700 3.7485810719010337
800 3.748620134397745
900 3.7486505163402017
1000 3.748674821894487
...
4700 3.7488470293379104
4800 3.748847998974433
4900 3.7488489290339553

b = 12500
print(b, (Y3(b*4)*b)/X1(b*4) / b)

12500 3.748876071891071
```

Коэффициент приближается к чему-то вроде 3.74888. Осталось доказать эту зависимость аналитически ;)

Comment: @insolor, Похоже не напутал, вроде всё так же считает и шустрее в разы)

Comment: @Isaev, здесь проблема не столько в рекурсии, сколько в том, что вы одни и те же значения высчитываете очень много раз. Добавив даже небольшое кэширование вы резко увеличите производительность (конечно, если памяти хватит)

Даже развернув так обе функции, сомневаюсь, что производительность будет нормальной.

Здесь, нарно, надо что-то типа [DP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) использовать.

Comment: @BOPOH, в идеале, конечно, согласен, но мне нужно вычислить 1 раз. Пусть это даже несколько минут займёт, но будет получен ответ.

Comment: @Isaev, а вам как срочно ответ получить надо? Я немного оптимизировал ваш код:

    def Y(m):
        p = 1
        j = 1
        o = 1
        for i in range(2, m + 1, 2):
            p *= (4 * (i - 1) * (i - 1) - 1);
            p += 7 * o;

            #X(i)
            o *= (4 * j * j - 1)
            j += 2

        return p

Для `Y(10**12)` первая версия работала бы 33 года, эта - всего 20 лет.

Здесь намного быстрее будет "хорошо напрячь математику", без этого вроде никак...

Comment: Ну да, на сообразительность же задача, а не на 20 лет ожидания) Думаю, вполне логично предположить, что деление одного на второе нужно выполнять сразу во второй функции, чтобы не вычислять оба результата отдельно, тогда изначально избежим очень больших чисел

Comment: @Isaev, выразил x(m) и y(m) через x(m-2) и y(m-2), получил следующее:

    y(m) / x(m) = y(m-2) / x(m-2) + 7 / ((2m-3) * (2m-1))

Продолжая вычисления получим, что необходимо найти сумму:

    1 + 7 / (2 * 2 - 3)(2 * 2 - 1) + 7 / (2 * 4 - 3)(2 * 4 - 1) + ... + 7 / (2 * m - 3)(2 * m - 1)

Думаю, с этим работать будет проще )

Comment: @Isaev, так вам моего комментария хватило? Или вам надо более подробно все расписать?

Если грубо, мы получаем ряд (как привести к этому читай [здесь](http://www.mathprofi.ru/kak_naiti_summu_ryada.html)):

    7/2 * (1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...)

Выражение в скобках равно pi / 4 ([док-во](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.ru/2007/11/leibniz-1-13-15-17.html)). Но поскольку pi мы высчитываем сами до определенного члена, то точность будет ниже.

Хотя если `print (... * b) / ...` означает что мы должны первые 12 цифр вывести, то ответ должен будет подойти.

Comment: @BOPOH, по вашим выкладкам получается что-то около 2.74, но опытным путем получается ближе к 3.75. И, думаю, стоит преобразовать ваши комментарии в ответ.

Comment: 1+ в начале наверное не посчитали вы